# Problema en php (!=)

Tags: php

Tengo un problema, llevo mas de 30 minutos comiendome la cabeza con este código, el problema es que siempre se eejctua que si, que es difrente cuando es igual como he podido comprobar en ese codigo, necesito ayuda. Aqui dejo el output que deja actualemente: 14969774-14969774

```
if(isset($_GET['gen'])) {
    if($_GET['gen'] != $_SESSION['id']) {
        echo $_GET['gen'];
        echo "-";
        echo $_SESSION['id'];
        //header('Location: selectgen.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

El problema es que el valor $_SESSION['id'] tiene un espacio (string(8) "14969774" string(9) "14969774 "), este valor se obtiene mediante el siguiente código cuando el usuairo se logea.

```
    ob_start();

    include 'inc/database.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `settings` LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $website = $row['website'];
        $favicon = $row['favicon'];
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { 
        session_start(); 
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($_POST['password']));

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1){
            header("Location: login.php?error=incorrect-password");
        exit;
        }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if($password != $row['password']){
                header("Location: login.php?error=incorrect-password");
          exit;
            }elseif($row['status'] == "0"){
                header("Location: login.php?error=banned");
          exit;
            }else{
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];


$_SESSION['rank'] = $row['rank'];
            $_SESSION['refer_name'] = $row['refer_name'];
            header("Location: index.php");
      exit;
        }
    }

}
```

***El problema era que había un espacio en la BD***

Comment: compara los len de las cadenas, no vaya a ser que alguno tenga caracteres raros o un espacio

Comment: tambien puede ser tema de los tipos de datos, que uno sea integer y el otro string, y el != te este devolviendo que son distintos. seria bueno que comprobaras tambien el tipo de dato de cada una de los elementos de cada array. Añade un `echo is_numeric($_GET['gen'])` para ver si es un integer (haz lo mismo para un `is_string` ) y a ver si tienes mas informacion con eso

Comment: Haciendo esto, me devuelve todas 1 menos echo is_numeric($_SESSION['id']); que no devuelve nada

Comment: @MarkusTechESP si `echo is_numeric($_SESSION['id']);` no te retona nada, es por que te esta dando FALSE, es decir `$_SESSION['id']` no es ni un número ni un string numérico.

Comment: Haz un cast, puede que tengas diferentes tipos de datos. `if((int)$_GET['gen'] != (int)$_SESSION['id'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si simulamos el contenido de `$_GET` y de `$_SESSION` con valores como estos:

```
$_GET=array('gen'=>14969774);
$_SESSION=array('id'=>14969774);
```

Incluso con alguno como cadena y otro como entero:

```
$_GET=array('gen'=>'14969774');
$_SESSION=array('id'=>14969774);
```

O ambos como cadena:

```
$_GET=array('gen'=>'14969774');
$_SESSION=array('id'=>'14969774');
```

En **todos** esos casos el código funciona de la forma esperada.

Es muy probable que en tu código ocurra algo como esto o parecido:

```
$_GET=array('gen'=>'14969774');
$_SESSION=array('id'=>'14969774 ');
```

En este caso el valor de `id` tiene un espacio en blanco al final y evalúa por esos los valores como distintos.

Esto se averigua fácil mediante un `var_dump`.

Propongo que verifiques tus variables primero con un ternario, así podrás usarlas y/o depurarlas de una forma  más fácil:

```
$gen=!empty ($_GET['gen'])    ? $_GET['gen']    : NULL;
$id= !empty ($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : NULL;
/*Probamos si son realmente iguales*/
var_dump($gen);
var_dump($id);

if($gen && $id) 
{
    $outPut=($gen != $id) ? "$gen - $id" : "Son iguales";
}
else
{
    $outPut="Faltan datos en GET o SESSION";
}
echo $outPut;
```

Comment: Perdón por tardar tanto en contestar jaja, tuvo exámenes y no pude ghacer nada., Esto es lo que me devuelve (string(8) "14969774" NULL Faltan datos en GET o SESSION)

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que el session id esta vacio

Comment: @MarkusTechESP el `NULL` que aparece correspondería al `id`, entonces, ese dato no está en tu variable de sesión. ¿Estás usando bien lo de las sesiones o no?

Comment: acabo de ver que faltaba el session start, pero comprobando veo que ocurre tal como tu decias 14969774 - devuelve un espacio

Comment: Como podria solucionarlo?, en la base de datos esta sin espacios. No llego a comprender porque existe este mismo

Comment: echo $_GET['gen'];
 echo "-";
 echo $_SESSION['id'];
 echo "-"; hize asi para comprobar si habia espacio jaja, y esto es lo que me devuelve (14969774-14969774 -)

Comment: string(8) "14969774" string(9) "14969774 " 14969774 - 14969774, esto es lo que me devuelve con el codigo que me pasaste.

Comment: @MarkusTechESP muestra en tu pregunta el código donde obtienes el valor y te diré a qué se debe el espacio. Pero primero asegúrate de que no está guardado con un espacio en la BD.

Comment: Respuesta actualizada :).

Comment: Y te confirmo que en la bd no tiene espacios

Comment: Pues te lo desconfirmo, habia un espacillo hay que no se veía a simple vista pero si lo abrias notabas que si

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda jaja

Comment: Ahora me devuelve esto string(8) "14969774" string(8) "14969774" Son iguales

Comment: Vamos a salir de duda, en el `else` donde asignas el valor, haz un `var_dump($row['id']);`  (quita los `var_dump` anteriores, de modo que sólo salga ese y no se confundan).

Comment: Buff, que alivio. Muchisimas gracias, ahora redacto el "gran error" jaja :)

Comment: Me alegro @MarkusTechESP. No te olvides de tu amigo `var_dump`, te va a sacar de muchos apuros, porque a veces esos espacios son invisibles de otro modo. Saludos.

Comment: Me lo apunto :).

Comment: tengo un problema, y es que los usuarios al crearse se generan con espacios, como podria eliminar esto?

Comment: Hay consultas SQL que corrigen eso, revisa entre las preguntas supongo que debe haber algo de eso y si no lo puedes preguntar indicando en que DBMS están tus tablas. Y debes controlar también los datos antes de ingresarlos, creando código que limpie los datos de espacios sobrantes y otras cosas.